# Django: Can you create a relationship with an auto-generated through table?

Tags: mysql, django

My code looks something like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

class Dish(models.Model):
  name    = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Meal(models.Model):
  name    = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  dishes  = models.ManyToManyField(Dish)
```

The many-to-many dishes field will result in a database table called 'myapp_meal_dishes' being created that includes id, meal_id, and dish_id fields.

I would like to add a MealDishEater model that connects with that auto-generated table:

```
class MealDishEater(models.Model):
  meal_dish = models.ForeignKey(MealDishes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  eater     = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
  ate_meal  = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Of course, that doesn't work, because MealDishes is not defined. Is there a way to do this or do I have to create my own through table?

Comment: i think ManyToMany 'through' relationship should work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the `ManyToManyField` intermediate model with the `through` attribute. So this should work:

```
class MealDishEater(models.Model):
    meal_dish = models.ForeignKey(Meal.dishes.through, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Personally, though, I always create explicit `through` models for `ManyToManyFields` rather than allowing such magic.

Comment: Thanks. JFYI, for others reading this, I didn't test this solution. I just went the explicit through table route.